# Arduino array definition

Tags: c, arduino

I'm reading through some code for an Arduino example and I came across this line:

`uint16_t pulses[100][2];`

It appears that this is defining a 100x2 array -- is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. It defines a 100x2 array of unsigned 16 bit integers.